# Where does "go mod init" get run?

Tags: go

I've been looking at how to structure Go projects and came across the following structure:

```
/cmd
   /app1
      main.go
   /app2
      main.go
/pgk
   /pkg1
      pkg.go
   /pkg2
      pkg.go
/internal
   /internal1
      internal.go
   /internal2
      internal.go
...
```

My understanding is the this is all one project (such as an API or something like that) and each "app" within the cmd folder are simply different entry points into the same overall application.

Is that correct?

Furthermore, at what level here do `go mod init <name>` get run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is an application.

- `go mod init` should be same label as the pkg, cmd, internal.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.